# How can I convert this fetch post request into an axios post request?

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch

Currently I am trying to convert a working fetch POST request into an Axios POST request. However, I keep getting this Error -> 'Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400'.

This is my **working** fetch request code below:

```
async function postData(url ='', data = { }) {

const response = await fetch(url, {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
body: JSON.stringify(data) });
let txoData = await response.json();
let a = txoData.payload.substring(68,134);
console.log(a);
console.log(txoData)

}

postData('https://merchantapi.taal.com/mapi/tx', { 'rawtx': rawtx })
.then(txoData => { return txoData })
.then(a => { return a })
```

and this is my **NOT working** convert to Axios attempt below:

```
async function postData() {

const response = await axios.post('https://merchantapi.taal.com/mapi/tx', {'rawtx': rawtx});
let txoData = await response.json();
let a = txoData.payload.substring(68,134);
console.log(a);
console.log(txoData)
}

postData()
.then(txoData => { return txoData })
.then(a => { return a })
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on this issue :)) x

Comment: You're not setting the required `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Comment: ah of course, where would I put the header in the axios statement?

Comment: Please check the documentation, give it a try on your own, and if you fail, edit the code in the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To pass custom headers while using axios supply an object containing the headers as the last argument